# HTML form to a Excel spreadsheet (database)

Tags: html, excel, forms, vbscript

I would like some help not modifying this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fillHidTable(){
var htqf; //-- hidden field
var rf; //-- retrieved field
for ( var i = 1; i < 5; i++ ) {
    rf = "htqf"+i;
    document.getElementById(rf).innerHTML = document.getElementById("Q"+i+"CALC").value;
}
tableToExcel('hidTable', 'Analysis Results');
}

var tableToExcel = (function() {
var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
        , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
}
})()
</script>

<title>HTML Form Data to Excel</title>

<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
<META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">


<style type="text/css" media="screen">
.divCenMid{font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14pt;font-style:normal;font-weight:700;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;margin:0;}
.allbdrCenMid{border:.75pt solid windowtext;color:#000;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;margin:0;}
.allbdrCenTop{border:.75pt solid windowtext;color:#000;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;margin:0;}
.allbdrLtMid{border:.75pt solid windowtext;color:#000;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;text-align:left;vertical-align:middle;margin:0;}
.allbdrLtTop{border:.75pt solid windowtext;color:#000;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;margin:0;}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<table width= "565px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-spacing:0;" id="QMSTable">
<col width="25px"/>
<col width="120px"/>
<col width="360px"/>
<col width="60px"/>
<tr>
    <td class="divCenMid" colspan = "4"> QMS Assessment</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="allbdrCenMid"> No</td>
    <td class="allbdrCenMid"> Criteria</td>
    <td class="allbdrLtMid"> Question</td>
    <td class="allbdrCenMid"> Score</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="allbdrCenTop"> Q1</td>
    <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Quality Unit Independency</td>
    <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Do you have the Quality Unit?</td>
    <td class="allbdrCenMid">
        <input id="Q1CALC" type="text" value="" class="nobdrCenMid" style="overflow:hidden; width:93% " name="Q1CALC"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="allbdrCenTop"> Q2</td>
    <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Apply PICS GMP</td>
    <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Which GMP regulation do you use?</td>
    <td class="allbdrCenMid">
        <input id="Q2CALC" type="text" value="" class="nobdrCenMid" style="overflow:hidden; width:93% " name="Q2CALC"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="allbdrCenTop"> Q3</td>
    <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Deviation or Non-conformance</td>
    <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Do you have a deviation or non-conformance procedure?</td>
    <td class="allbdrCenMid">
        <input id="Q3CALC" type="text" value="" class="nobdrCenMid" style="overflow:hidden; width:93% " name="Q3CALC"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="allbdrCenTop"> Q4</td>
    <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Complaint</td>
    <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Do you have a customer complaint procedure?</td>
    <td class="allbdrCenMid">
        <input id="Q4CALC" type="text" value="" class="nobdrCenMid" style="overflow:hidden; width:93% " name="Q4CALC"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<div id="hidTable" style="display: none">
<table id="testTable">
    <caption>Supplier Risk Analysis</caption>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Question</th>
        <th>Score</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Q1</td>
        <td>Do you have the Quality Unit?</td>
        <td id="htqf1">-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Q2</td>
        <td>Apply PICS GMP?</td>
        <td id="htqf2">-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Q3</td>
        <td>Do you have a deviation or non-conformance procedure?</td>
        <td id="htqf3">-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Q4</td>
        <td>Do you have a customer complaint procedure?</td>
        <td id="htqf4">-</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="fillHidTable()" name=PatientDatabase value="Export Data to Excel">
</body>
</html>
```

It makes a web based form which I can play with and edit, but is there a way I can just change the last button to save the excel table into cells to make more of a database and is there a way I can save it to a specific file and to have it fill in or append the data.

Answer (score 1):

you can convert HTML div to excel

```
 var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))

  }
})()
```

Comment: Alright now I dont get the .xls.xls error anymore but is there a way to make this a self populating database so it just populates the 4 fields into 4 columns in excel